# How to refactor XSD so that unmarshalling does not return JAXBElement

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following schema:

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns:bar="http://www.foo.org/bar"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        targetNamespace="http://www.foo.org/bar"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox" jaxb:version="2.1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="unit" type="bar:unit" />

    <xsd:complexType name="unit">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <annox:annotate>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="unit")</annox:annotate>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any processContents="skip" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

When I unmarshall this XML

```xml
<unit xmlns="http://www.foo.org/bar">
    <text>Name</text>
</unit>
```

the returned object is `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<Unit>`, however I would like to get `org.foo.bar.Unit` back. I need this because unmarshalling in my case happens implicitly by JAX-RS provider or SpringWeb.

Observations:

- If I remove/replace `<xsd:any processContents="skip" />` declaration, JAXB starts to return `org.foo.bar.Unit`.
- If I remove `<xsd:element name="unit" type="bar:unit" />` declaration, JAXB starts to return `org.foo.bar.Unit` (although one need to disable validation during unmarshalling).

Thus I would say that given XSD is the smallest XSD that demonstrates the problem.

Questions: Why JAXB wraps `org.foo.bar.Unit` into `JAXBElement` for above combination? From what I see, there is no way the XSD type `unit` can have tag name different from `unit`, so why JAXB needs this factory method?

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.foo.org/bar", name = "unit")
public JAXBElement<Unit> createUnit(Unit value) { ... }
```

The project demonstrating the problem for JAXB 2.2.7 is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8x7w1qt15116rqg/jaxb_element_test.7z?dl=1). When run it outputs the following:

```
Running org.foo.bar.UnitTest
>>> Class is: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
>>> XML is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><unit xmlns="http://www.foo.org/bar"><text>Name</text></unit>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.318 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Ian's answer,
Any `complex` element that is named by `root` element will have factory method annotated with `@XmlElementDecl()`.

You can resolve this, by moving the `complex` type declaration inline like below.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns= "http://www.foo.org/bar" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    targetNamespace="http://www.foo.org/bar" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
    jaxb:version="2.1" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="unit">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <annox:annotate>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="unit")
                    </annox:annotate>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:any processContents="skip" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**ObjectFactory.class** (no `JAXBElement` factory method generated here)

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: org.foo.bar
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Unit }
     * 
     */
    public Unit createUnit() {
        return new Unit();
    }

}
```

**Test class:**

```
@Test
public void testUnmarshalling() throws JAXBException, SAXException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Unit.class);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    unmarshaller.setSchema(SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
            .newSchema(new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("common.xsd"))));

    Object unit = unmarshaller.unmarshal(getClass().getResourceAsStream("unit.xml"));

    System.out.println(">>> Class is: " + unit.getClass().getName());

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(unit, writer);

    System.out.println(">>> XML is: " + writer.toString());

    //assertTrue(unit instanceof Unit);
}
```

**Test xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<unit xmlns="http://www.foo.org/bar">
    <text>Name</text>
</unit>
```

**output :**

```
>>> Class is: org.foo.bar.Unit
>>> XML is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><unit xmlns="http://www.foo.org/bar"><text>Name</text></unit>
```

Comment: If I remove `<xsd:element name="unit" type="bar:unit" />` from schema, JAXB still results the same "problematic" `ObjectFactory`. Indeed, XML which I provided, does not validate. But JAXB still fails to marshal it to `Unit` domain model. More over I hope you can agree with me, that even with original XSD there is no alternative for `unit` type to be used with another element name, hence wrapping is not necessary. Sounds like non-optimal model is being generated by JAXB.

Comment: I disagree. `unit` type if defined without wrapping in the `<xs:element>` means it can be referenced by other schemas if you circulate it around. you cannot restrict it from using only by `<xs:element name="unit">`. It is also the same reason, when you remove `<xsd:element name="unit" type="bar:unit" />`, the `xs:complextype` can be referenced as it is not contained in another `xs:element`. btw what is problematic means? and  I suppose above xsd wont generate JAXBElement factory method, if thats what you mean.

Comment: please see update that generated `ObjectFactory.class` without `JAXBElement` factory method.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think we are on the same rails in discussion as with [Ian Roberts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39588894/267197) in his answer. I think JAXB can be more intelligent and choose the creator method without `XMLElememt` wrapper for root element declaration (if several then choose first), and generate more creator methods for other element declarations that refer the same type. When we compile the model JAXB knows about all XSDs involved, so it can take a proper decision, but (and it would surprise me) perhaps there is a way to mix different models in runtime?

Comment: @dma_k " When we compile the model JAXB knows about all XSDs involved, so it can take a proper decision " - what about you create a new schema in future and want to refer to `unit` type? So if you define it as global element, you are telling `XJC` that you will want to use it anywhere as you want. Unlike the `complex type` which is contained inside the element which cannot be referenced elsewhere. so `XJC` does exactly what you provided in the schema and i think its just how `JAXB` works.

Comment: If you create "a new schema in future", how do you compile it into the model? That will be a completely new model, you can't combine it with "old" model. At least I don't know any way of doing so. And that "new" model indeed would need some helper factory methods to create new elements, but still JAXB can choose one of root elements to be referred from `@XmlRootElement`, while others are created by additional factory methods (so that `@XmlRootElement.name` is different from `@XmlElementDecl.name`). However I agree that this is "nice to have" feature of JAXB, which  is currently not there.

Answer (score 3):

> From what I see, there is no way the XSD type unit can have tag name different from unit, so why JAXB needs this factory method?

On the contrary - you will always get a `JAXBElement` when your schema uses a named complex type by reference. With a named complex type there's always the possibility that the type might be used for a different element (maybe in another importing schema) or that the element may use a subtype of the named type rather than the top type itself.

Unwrapped root elements are used when the global `xsd:element` declaration has a nested anonymous `complexType`, as in that scenario the unmarshaller knows that those kinds of substitutions can't happen.

Comment: I think you are wrong. At least my experiment shows that. Take original XSD and replace `<xsd:any processContents="skip" />` with `<xsd:element name="text" type="xsd:string" />` (so the content of `unit` is now more strictly defined). Run the project – unit test passed. A both `xsd:complexType` and `xsd:element` are there.

Comment: Another observation is that `unit` type can only be represented as `unit` element (and there is no other alternative). JAXB knows about that, but still generates the wrapper. In other words factory method with `@XmlElementDecl.name` equals to (`@XmlType.name` or `@XmlRootElement.name`) is not necessary.

Comment: @dma_k "Another observation is that unit type can only be represented as unit element (and there is no other alternative)" - no, the unit type can be used by any other schema that imports this one.  The only way the generator can know _for certain_ that the type can't be used elsewhere is when it's an anonymous type nested inside the element declaration.

Comment: Actually I found an article [Separate compilation in the JAXB](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2006/09/05/separate-compilation-jaxb-ri-21) that explains how to combine two separately generated models, so indeed JAXB needs to generate helpers in `ObjectFactory` for elements in top XSD (the one that includes given one). For such simple model as given in example, JAXB should assign the 1st root element (`{http://www.foo.org/bar}unit`) to be seialized/deserialized using `@XmlRootElement`, and other root elements – using `@XmlElementDecl` in `ObjectFactory`. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something like this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Unit.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

JAXBElement<Unit> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
        file), Unit.class);
Unit unit = root.getValue();
```

Try maybe:

```
Unit unit = JAXBIntrospector.getValue(jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
        file), Unit.class);
```

Comment: I know that I can unwrap the object from `JAXBElement`, but I would like to use the model object as controller like `@RequestMapping("/post") public void submit(@RequestBody Unit unit) { ... }`. Unfortunately, explicit unwrapping does not happen neither in Spring MVC nor in RESTEasy.

Comment: You can add your own messageconverter for such things in spring, if you want to...

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately I can only control the schema, not the Java code. In other words, adding custom message converter is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to work with, either a javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement instance or an instance of @XmlRootElement annotated Java class:

```
public <T> T unmarshal(Source queryResults, String modelPackages) {
        T resultObject = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(modelPackages);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            resultObject = (T) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(u.unmarshal(queryResults));
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return resultObject;
    }
```

Edit:

You have reason, I putted this code because is a code I did for a project and that I think that is more reusable.

So for you question:

Why JAXB wraps org.foo.bar.Unit into JAXBElement for above combination?

because you are telling it to do it with `<xsd:any processContents="skip" />` :)

Well, when you put this in your XSD you acts like if you use the annotation:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=false)
```

With that tag / annotation you are saying to JAXB: 'here comes something, a bunch of nodes, (@XmlAnyElement) that you should not parse never; let it as DOM object, please (lax=false)' try with:

```
processContents=lax
```

This way it should try to parse your xml to domain object and will return Unit if it can find it or JAXBElement otherway or:

```
processContents=strict
```

Which will try to parse it to your domain object

Comment: Thanks for additional information. I don't see the logical connection between the element in `unit` (which is basically DOM), and wrapping `Unit` into `JAXBElement`. Schema tells that on top level there could be `unit` and nothing else (no ambiguities).

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I have found an answer, which is basically given by Kohsuke Kawaguchi in [Why does JAXB put @XmlRootElement sometimes but not always](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2006/03/03/why-does-jaxb-put-xmlrootelement-sometimes-not-always). It turned out that the decision to add `@XmlRootElement` annotation is antagonist to generation of helper factory method. One should enable `<xjc:simple />` optimization and JAXB will assume that all elements are root elements:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:bar="http://www.foo.org/bar"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
            targetNamespace="http://www.foo.org/bar"
            jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:simple />
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:element name="unit" type="bar:unit" />

    <xsd:complexType name="unit">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any processContents="skip" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```